# Difference between mac and desktop version of Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I do not understand the difference between [the two versions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu). I am going to run it on Vmware Fusion on a mac, does it will make a difference ?

Comment: Since you are running Lubuntu within VMware, any driver incongruity should be handled by VMWare, so it should not matter which version you get. You may as well grab the Mac version so that you will have the disc should you choose to switch to Lubuntu on your Mac permanently.

Answer (score 1):

Apple is a hardware company with proprietary hardware. The Mac version of Lubuntu has Mac's specific firmware and drivers loaded on the kernel while the desktop version of Lubuntu does not.